# Spring Boot, delete/patch запрос

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, delete, httpwebrequest

Пытаюсь реализовать проект на Spring Boot + Spring Security + Spring Data JPA.
Возникла проблема с DELETE запросом. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему или направьте где почитать.

### Класс контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class ProjectController {
   private final ProjectRepository projectRepository;

   @Autowired
   public ProjectController(ProjectRepository projectRepository) {
      this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
   }

   @DeleteMapping("/feed/{project_id}")
   public String deleteProject(@PathVariable("project_id") long id) {
      projectRepository.deleteById(id);
      return "redirect:/feed";
   }
}
```

### Форма запроса:

```
    <form th:method="delete" th:action="@{/feed/{project_id}(project_id = ${project.id})}">
       <strong th:text="${project.name}">1</strong>
       <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>
```

в итоге из бд ничего не удаляется

Изменил код для более глубокого понимания:

### Класс контроллера:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/feed")
public class ProjectController {

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getAll() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        view.setViewName("/feed");
        return view;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String create() {
        return "Create new project";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getOne() {
        return "Get one project";
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public String update() {
        System.out.println("Project is deleted");
        return "Project is updated";
    }
}
```

### Формы запроса:

```
    <form method="post" th:action="@{/feed}">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <form th:method="patch" th:action="@{/feed/1}">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Patch" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <form th:method="delete" th:action="@{/feed/1}">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

В итоге запросы GET, POST отрабатывают отлично, а DELETE и PATCH - никак, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: странно что вы используете url в шаблоне, а не название маршрута. Это не совсем правильно

Comment: вы имеете в виду в th:action? не могли бы вы подсказать где посмотреть как правильно делать?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят!

Если в проекте используется Spring Security то в каждом запросе автоматически передаются csrf токены запросы PUT, PATCH, DELETE необходимо передавать через thymeleaf:

```
<form th:method="delete" th:action="@{/feed/1}">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Таким образом после генерации тело запроса выглядит так:

```
<form method="post" action="/feed/1">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="беспорядочный набор символов">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" wfd_invisible="true">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Thymeleaf генерирует скрытые методы, а их необходимо разрешить.
Я знаю только о двух способах их разрешения:

1. в файле помеченном аннотацией @Configuration или @SpringBootApplication необходимо создать следующий бин:

   ```
   @Bean
   public FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
       FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());
       filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("/*"));
       return filterRegistrationBean;
   }
   ```
2. В файле application.properties добавить:

   ```
   spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
   ```

Выберите один из способов и переходите к последующим проблемам)